# How to retrieve Organization units from Active Directory using graph Api

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api, directoryservices

I have gone through [Graph Api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to retrive Organizational Units but I can't find the Api to fetch a collection of Organizational Units in each group for a specific user.

Can you guys give some reference links?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Entra doesn't expose Organizational Units (OUs) as they're a feature of on-premises Active Directory and are not available in Azure AD. Thus, Microsoft Graph API doesn't provide a way to retrieve OUs.

Also note that in Entra, the OUs are not a feature, instead there are AUs see the [Microsoft Graph administrativeUnit  Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/administrativeunit?view=graph-rest-1.0)